# I´m trying to make a unit test in springboot but the test throw me java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

When i try to create a class test always throw me the next error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImplement': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.sophosproject.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I've spent hours trying to solve the problem but I can't find a real solution, maybe you could help me to find a solution.

**UserServiceImplement CLASS**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImplement implements UserService{

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public GenericResponse listAllUser() {

    var apiResponse = new GenericResponse();

    try{
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        if(userList == null){
            apiResponse.setOperationSuccess(true);
            apiResponse.setMessage("No Records");
            return apiResponse;
        }

        long totalRecords = userList.stream().count();

        apiResponse.setOperationSuccess(true);
        apiResponse.setObjectResponse(userList);
        apiResponse.setTotalRecords(totalRecords);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        apiResponse.setOperationSuccess(false);
        apiResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }

    return apiResponse;
}

@Override
public User getUser(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@Override
public User createUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public User updateUser(User user) {
    User userDb = getUser(user.getIdUser());
    if(null == userDb){
        return null;
    }
    userDb.setNameUser(user.getNameUser());
    userDb.setLastNameUser(user.getLastNameUser());
    userDb.setUserCode(user.getUserCode());
    userDb.setEmailUser(user.getEmailUser());
    userDb.setUserAddress(user.getUserAddress());
    userDb.setPosition(user.getPosition());
    userDb.setTaskList(user.getTaskList());

    return userRepository.save(userDb);
}

@Override
public User deleteUser(Long id) {
    User userDb = getUser(id);
    if(null == userDb){
        return null;
    }

    userDb.setStateUser(false);
    return userRepository.save(userDb);
}

@Override
public List<User> findByTask(Task task) {
    return userRepository.findByTask(task);
}
}
```

**UserServiceImplementTest CLASS**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = UserServiceImplement.class)
class UserServiceImplementTest {

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    userService = new UserServiceImplement(userRepository);

    User userTest = User.builder().idUser(1L)
                        .nameUser("Michael").lastNameUser("Torres")
                        .userCode("MTO").emailUser("michaeltorresos92@gmail.com")
                        .userAddress("KR103").position("Developer").stateUser(true)
                        .taskList((List<Task>) Task.builder().idTask(1).build()).build();

    Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(1L))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(userTest));

}

@Test
public void whenValidGetId_ThenReturnUser(){
    User found = userService.getUser(1L);

    Assertions.assertThat(found.getNameUser()).isEqualTo("Michael");
}

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.project.sophos</groupId>
<artifactId>SophosProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SophosProject</name>
<description>Demo project for Sophos</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**UserRepository interface**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

public List<User> findByTask(Task task);
}
```

**SophosProjectApplication class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project.sophosproject"})
public class SophosProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SophosProjectApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

**UserRepository Interface**

```
public interface UserService {
public GenericResponse listAllUser();
public GenericResponse getUser(Integer id);
public User createUser(User user);
public User updateUser (User user);
public User deleteUser(Integer id);
}
```

Comment: Ditch the first 2 lines of your `@BeforeEach` method, replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean`, add `@Autowired` to the `UserService` field and re-run your test.

Answer (score 3):

Spring cannot find a `UserRepository` bean, because the way the test is currently configured causes it to be excluded.

Take a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#classes--) for `classes` on the `@SpringBootTest` annotation:

> The component classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext. Can also be specified using @ContextConfiguration(classes=...). **If no explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested @Configuration classes, before falling back to a @SpringBootConfiguration search.**

That means that *if* you provide `classes`, then Spring will attempt to configure *only* those bean classes. In this case, your class under test, `UserServiceImplement`, depends on a `UserRepository`- but your `@SpringBootTest(classes = UserServiceImplement.class)` annotation dictates that only `UserServiceImplement` will be instantiated, and therefore the dependency cannot be satisfied.

If you remove `classes=...` and instead just use `@SpringBootTest`, your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class will be loaded, and the whole application context will be created (including the missing repository) as opposed to just the one class specified.

---

An aside, as your test class is currently written, there's not much of a benefit to instantiating an application context or marking the test class as `@SpringBootTest`. Doing that is typically reserved for integration tests, where multiple components need to be loaded so that their integrations can be tested (hence the name).

Instead, you've mocked the only dependency, `UserService`, and are manually instantiating `UserServiceImplement`. That means you've not used Spring at all in your test. Your test is testing one unit, `UserServiceImplement`, and therefore doesn't benefit from the integration environment provided by `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Hi bro, even when i tried to run the main class it throws me the error, check this out please:
onfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImplement' defined in file [C:\Users\mikey\Sophos\sophosproject\SophosProject\target\classes\com\project\sophosproject\service\UserServiceImplement.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0 nested exception is org.springframework

Comment: you can check UserRepository interface it'sok ?

Comment: @MichaelTorresOspina Can you edit the question to add the packages of `UserServiceImplement`, `UserRepository `, and your `@SpringBootApplication` classes?

Comment: is done, Could you check?

Comment: @MichaelTorresOspina While I would guess that there is most likely an issue with your component scanning, my suggestion would be that you post a new question after carefully reading [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It wouldn't surprise me if you find the issue yourself while trying to produce that. And if not, the people answering your new question will have an easier time finding the issue. I'm suggesting a new question as the scope of this one was focused on the tests, so my answer was specific to the tests.

Comment: ok i will check the information thanks